# AviFile API: adding a WAV file to an AVI file without loading it into RAM

Tags: .net, winapi, interop

In my C# application, I'm doing interop to the AviFile API. I want to add a WAV file as the audio track to a silent AVI file.

The code below works without problems. However, it loads the entire WAV file into RAM.
How can I achieve the same thing, without needing that much memory?

If that's impossible using the AviFile API, is there any C# library to achieve the same?

```
Avi.AVISTREAMINFO streamInfo = new Avi.AVISTREAMINFO();
Avi.PCMWAVEFORMAT streamFormat = new Avi.PCMWAVEFORMAT();
int streamLength = 0;

IntPtr rawData = newStream.GetStreamData(ref streamInfo, ref streamFormat, ref streamLength);
IntPtr waveData = rawData;
IntPtr aviStream;
int result = Avi.AVIFileCreateStream(aviFile, out aviStream, ref streamInfo);


result = Avi.AVIStreamSetFormat(aviStream, 0, ref streamFormat, Marshal.SizeOf(streamFormat));

Avi.AVIStreamWrite(aviStream, 0, streamLength, waveData, streamLength, Avi.AVIIF_KEYFRAME, 0, 0);

Avi.AVIStreamRelease(aviStream);

Marshal.FreeHGlobal(waveData);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can manually open the wav file and read the data. In that case you would have to manually interleave A/V data and create the avi on your own. Adding JUNK chunks, indexes and other required things could be tricky. But, if you know the avi/RIFF architecture, it's 100% doable.

Comment: Thanks! Ideally I'd like a quick and easy solution using the AviFile API, as I'm already using that.